# Why function's (self, index)'s index doesn't get called inside the function and the function still works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this snippet of working and tested Python code:

```
def renameFiles(self, index):
    filename = self._filenames[self._current_index]
    newFilename = self.createNewFilename()
    self.currentFileName.setText(newFilename)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)
    fullPath = os.path.join(dirname, newFilename)
    os.replace(filename,fullPath)
    self._filenames[self._current_index] = fullPath
    self.current_index = self._current_index
```

Why is it that the ***index*** in the ***def renameFiles(self, index):*** isn't called in anywhere inside the function and yet the function still works? (It may not be the most optimized and beautiful code, but still works)

I've searched for manuals and guides for hours now and still can't wrap my head around this. And I can't progress in my project until I understand how this works.

I'll gladly post more of the code if needed.

Comment: just because a function has an argument doesn't mean it has to be used inside it, however it is required that it is provided when calling the function (unless there is a default value set). also it wouldn't be "calling" a variable but more of referencing

Comment: I would try removing `index` as an argument and see if the function still works as expected. Also, how is `self._current_index` set and does it have any relation to the value of `index`?

Comment: also also, why do You ask this question about a method since a method would require a class to be in (I assume so because of the `self` argument) meaning that You are dealing with classes without knowing that arguments don't have to be used (which would mean that You are dealing with more complex Python code without knowing the very basics)

Comment: Thanks! Yes! Actually removing the index still keeps the function working, interesting! self._current_index is really important but yes, I don't know its relation to this index - maybe the index wasn't truly needed, I shall test some more. Here's the full code if needed. Yes, one class is present: https://gist.github.com/manujarvinen/fc727cd1d12b6ef2c708a40c32cc3ce1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, a user-defined function can have as many "non-callable" arguments as you want. For example, the following is a valid function:

```
def f(a, b, c, d, e):
    print("Hello World")
```

However, unless you provide default values for variables a through e, calling the function without specifying them will raise an exception

Comment: I wonder how the code worked with the index being there. I'm not sure if it was given a value. Here's the full code if you have time to look: https://gist.github.com/manujarvinen/fc727cd1d12b6ef2c708a40c32cc3ce1 - I've now removed the index from the renameFiles function, though.

Comment: It's not a 'best practice', I agree. A function shouldn't request arguments it doesn't need. But in some occasions it's practical to do so (I can give you an example if you're curious)

Comment: Imagine you have the following very simple function: def f(g, x): g(x). All it does is call function g() with argument x. In some occasions,  this type of function (f) is used when you want the user to create his own function g which may or may not require x as an argument. One might create g as: def g(x): return x*2. But one might also create g as def g(): print("Done."). If you pass this second function to f(), it will raise an exception. Why? Because f assumes that g requires x as an argument (which is currently doesn't).
So, a way to fix it is by defining g as: def g(x): print("Done.").

Comment: Long story short, you as a programmer do this when you don't know exactly what the user-defined function will require.  However, very often it is also simply a mistake (someone forgot to remove it from the arguments)

Comment: I think I got it, even though I'm a mere beginner, thank you very much for the explanation :) - So, I guess that in my case all the unnecessary arguments need to be cleaned away, if possible